# Setup Windows Storage Server as SAN Storage

Tags: storage, windows-server-2016, san

we want to setup a Windows Storage Server 2016 with FibreChannel and 2 Shelfs as SAN Storage.

We need this to connect the Blades at the Storage.

Blades all have installed FC HBAs, but Windows only provide iSCSI Initiators for LUN but not for FibreChannel.

Is there a solution, or should we use an other software as filer (FreeNas, Nexenta, OpenFiler)?

Answer (score 7):

Windows doesn't do anything like that, and unfortunately first choice for target-side storage stack StarWind doesn't do any FC as well. There are other Windows options, but they are very very expensive! What you can do is... use FreeBSD virtual machine with something like scst inside.

https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/46591/

https://gathering.tweakers.net/forum/list_messages/1613088

Pass-thru your FC HBA with a PCI pass-thru or SR-IOV and you'll be good!

Comment: FreeBSD or Linux on bare metal or virtual machine exposing storage to either bare metal or virtual Windows. ESOS-Project http://www.esos-project.com/ might fit too.